# List Json Children on Page Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm creating a project, for-fill form. In Home I show you a list of forms, from the moment you choose the form you want to respond to and open a new page that is for lists. But I can not list it as questions. I'm looking for the data without firebase, when I'm selecting the form, I get the data inside the key of the given form and put it in a class template interface. But at the time of doing ngFor, I can not get this array and list it as questions. I think you need to map the data, but I do not know how. Any tips for solving this problem? Thanks.

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
  console.log(this.navParams.get('questions'));
  this.questions = this.navParams.get('questions');
}
```

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let q of questions" detail-push>  
      <ion-label>{{q | json}}</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
        <ion-option value="S" selected="true">Sim</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="N">Não</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I'm facing following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:2537)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12092)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AnswerQuestionsPage.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:2537)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12092)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AnswerQuestionsPage.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1350
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/87281 where we converted the json data to array and it worked!

Or it looks like you want

<li *ngFor="let data of youitemdata.childitemdata">
{{data }}
</li>

Comment: So I tried to convert json to array but I could not. And the github link is entering error 404.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `console.log(this.navParams.get('questions'));` In case of '[object Object]' please show us what `console.log(JSON.parse(this.navParams.get('questions')));` outputs...

Comment: please update this.questions console value in your question?